# How to change this simple code into funciton to get total number of observation of each dataframes within a list?

Tags: r, list, function, apply, lapply

Here is an example list of dfs.

```
var1 <- rnorm(10)
var2 <- rnorm(10)
  df1 <-data.frame(var1,var2)
var1 <- rnorm(14)
var2 <- rnorm(14)
  df2 <-data.frame(var1,var2)
var1 <- rnorm(17)
var2 <- rnorm(17)
  df3 <-data.frame(var1,var2)
df.list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

My calculation:

```
n <- table(var1, var2)
N <- length(df1$var1)  # !!!! df1?
test1 <- N * n
test2 <- n/N
list <-list(test1, test2)
```

Now I want to turn it into a function in order to apply this function on the list of dfs at the same time.

```
 fun <- function(var1, var2){
    n <- table(var1, var2)
    N <- length(df1$var1); N  # !!!!!
    test1 <- N * n
    test2 <- n/N
    list <-list(test1, test2)
    return(list)
  }

outputs <- lapply(df.list, function(x) 
   x$output <- fun(var1, var2))
```

But I cant get the way to tell R to take length of each df not just df1 when calculating N inside of the function. Is there anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

lapply just iterate through all elements of list and apply given function. With you that is data frame object, you can acces the columns of that x as you would of any other data frame. Also avoid calling variables that are not declared in the function. :)

```
 fun <- function(var1, var2){
    n <- table(var1, var2)
    N <- length(var1); N  # !!!!!
    test1 <- N * n
    test2 <- n/N
    list <-list(test1, test2)
    return(list)
  }

a <- lapply(df.list, function(x)fun(x[,1],x[,2])   )
```